# AWS How to restore database backup or snapshot to a different server?

Tags: sql-server, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, restore

We have an MS SQL Server running on AWS (Amazon) RDS which automatically takes backup at night. I want to restore this backup to an archive RDS instance automatically, i.e. restore the backup to another SQL Server .
Whats the best way to do this? (I would prefer not to use sql scripts.)

Comment: *"automatically takes backup"* -- are you talking about RDS snapshots, or a different kind of backup?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yes the RDS snapshots

Comment: "backup to another SQL Server" -- do you mean MSSQL server other than AWS RDS ?

Comment: @mootmoot another MSSQL in AWS RDS .

Answer (score 2):

AWS Provides facility to take Entire server(MSSQL server service  and entire database) backup as a snapshot. You can create another server as original server. you can not restore database only to already running server. For that you just take database dump and restore that dump to another server ( But this is useful way only your database size is smaller).

For your reference

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_RestoreFromSnapshot.html